# jQuery UI Datepicker displaying incorrectly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to add a form to a web page containing an input that is to display the jQuery UI datepicker widget once a user has clicked on the input just as it does on the [jQuery UI Site](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

I have followed the steps outlined in the demo but when i load the page the calander is displaying full width dow the bottom of the page inbetween the closing footer tag and the closing body tag.

I can get it to work inside [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uz5U4/) but cannot recreate in on my web page.

I am referencing the following scripts in the head of my document

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: give your website link

Comment: Have you also included the jQuery UI css?

Comment: look for any unclosed tags in your markup

Comment: common mistake `<link rel="stylesheet" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>`

Comment: Yeah I have the css referenced                                     <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether without seeing the full code.  *Even without jQuery UI Stylesheet it should have worked.*

Here I have given full working code

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <!--START CHOOSE DATE-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('.date_select').datepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <p class="date_picker">
            <label for="date_input" class="select">Date:</label>
            <input type="text" name="date_input" id="date_input" class="date_select" />
        </p>
        <!--END CHOOSE DATE-->
    </body>
</html>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4sYW2/1/)

Comment: Its basically popping up at the very bottom of the page full width as opposed to a dropdown from the input itself

Comment: @psycho that what I have said in my answer, that make use of my code in a separate file and try whether it is working locally

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple case of one of my closing tags not being correct. I put the markup through the W3C validator and it helped me spot the problem.

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into this - another solution.

Make sure that there is not too much text for the space.

In my case I was setting the days of the week to longer words and it forced the table width to overflow.